# Flutter bottom navigation bar: where to place index counter in scaffold so it will work?

Tags: flutter, navigationbar, bottom-navigation-bar

I am struggling with implementation of bottom navigation bar. Specifically, I am trying to place 'index' with the body as in all examples that I found, but body element already has Responsive screen inside. The problem is: even though I have navigation bar displayed, it doesn't redirect to the specific route and doesn't highlight selected navigation item.

Could you please help me to fix it?

The sequence of my code looks following way:

```
    class LevelSelectionScreen extends StatefulWidget {
    const LevelSelectionScreen({super.key});
    @override
    _LevelSelectionScreenState createState() => 
    _LevelSelectionScreenState();

    }
    class _LevelSelectionScreenState extends State<LevelSelectionScreen> {
    int _selectedIndex = 0;
    void _onItemTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedIndex = index;
    });
    }


    @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     final playerProgress = context.watch<PlayerProgress>();
     int _selectedIndex = 0;
     final pages = [
     const MainMenuScreen(),
     const AvailabilityScreen(),
     const SettingsScreen(),
     ];

return Scaffold(
    extendBody: true,
    bottomNavigationBar: NavigationBar(
      height: 60,
      selectedIndex: _selectedIndex,
      elevation: 100,
      onDestinationSelected: _onItemTapped,
      destinations: [
      NavigationDestination(
        icon: Icon(Icons.home),
        selectedIcon: Icon(Icons.home),
        label: 'home',

      ),
      NavigationDestination(
        icon: Icon(Icons.book),
        selectedIcon: Icon(Icons.book),
        label: 'learn',
      ),
      NavigationDestination(
        icon: Icon(Icons.gamepad),
        selectedIcon: Icon(Icons.gamepad),
        label: 'play',
      ),
       NavigationDestination(
        icon: Icon(Icons.person),
        selectedIcon: Icon(Icons.person),
        label: 'profile',
      ),
      ]),
    backgroundColor: Color(0XFFFEF4DF),
    
    body: 
    
            ResponsiveScreen(    
        squarishMainArea: Padding(
          child: Column(
            children: [
          
              Row(
                children: [
                  Align(
                    InkResponse(
                      onTap: 
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: 
                        child: CircleAvatar(
                 
                          child: Icon(
                            Icons.person,
                            
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Align(
                 
                    child: InkResponse(
                      onTap: 
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: 
                        child: CircleAvatar(
                          radius: 20,
                          child: Icon(
                            Icons.home,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
         
              Padding(
              
                child: Center(
              ),

              Expanded(
                child: ListView(
                  children: [
                    for (final level in gameLevels)
                      Padding(
                      
                        child: ListTile(
                          )

        rectangularMenuArea: SizedBox()));
     }

    }
```

Comment: can you include more about `ResponsiveScreen`

Answer (score 1):

the problem that the var  `int _selectedIndex = 0;` is defined inside the build function. so that with every rebuild the _selectedIndex will set to 0.